# Timestamp incorrect hours

Tags: python, timestamp

In my Python program I use a timestamp.
It is in this form:

```
timestamp=time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
```

The minutes and seconds are correct, but the hours are incorrect (10h actuality, 8h in my Python program).

It is in a MySQL database(raspberry pi) that i put the datetime. I once tried the following:

from datetime import * import pytz 
utc=pytz.timezone('Europe/Brussels') 
today = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=utc)

still shows two hours difference.... 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you add a bit more context? Is `time` the time module or something else? Are you sure the timezone hasn't been changed?

Comment: Edit your question, instead of adding it as an answer. What I mean is that `time.strftime()` uses the local time, if you don't pass a time to it.

Comment: What would I have to use instead of time.strftime()?

Comment: I'm saying that `time.strftime()` results in the same time as your computer, given that the Python script is executed on your computer. Thus I can't replicate the problem. In other words, there is another problem at hand.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks.
And the time of my computer is not the time when I see in my taskbar(
because that is correct)?
would you know where i can see / change

Comment: What do you see in your task bar (windows I guess), and what do you see in the output, **exactly**?

Comment: What output do you get for `time.tzname` and `time.timezone`?

Comment: One moment, please

Comment: I have tried many things but I see nothing with time.timezone or time.tzname.
There must be something in brackets?

Comment: What computer is your python code running on?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Has a MySQL Database in the raspberry also  timezone settings?

Comment: I solved it by using this link http://www.geeklee.co.uk/update-time-zone-on-raspberry-pi-with-raspbian/